# Do Wonders have to be physical objects?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, genius-the-transgression

I've been reading some of the flavor text in Genius: The Transgression, and I've noticed a good deal of it mentioning pre-Genius discoveries that are not physical inventions, i.e. a black-box codebreaking algorithm, or alien mathematics. That got me wondering: what if one were to try to craft a Wonder that was not directly tied to a physical object? Now, I wouldn't say something like "programming language with which to hack reality" or anything that would too obviously resemble magic (though such a thing would be interesting should someone try a Mage/Genius crossover involving an additional "arcane" Axiom, but that's another story); I mean such things as:

- a Katastrofi wonder that is more or less the Anti-Life equation, a mathematical formula that is fatal to any thinking being or machine that tries to process it;
- an Exelexi/Metapropi Wonder that is a type of music- not just a particular instrument, but a specific set of frequencies, that, when strung together in certain combinations, can manipulate objects in various ways;
- an Epikrato mnemonic device that lets a Genius hide simple subliminal commands, as well as a trigger word or phrase, within spam email or text messages that implant themselves into the mind of the intended recipient- provided he or she actually reads the message in question.

Etc. I suppose in the end this would end up being Storyteller's call anyway, but I guess in short I'm asking if Wonders can be mental/metaphysical concepts or processes rather than being limited to robots, gadgets, and monsters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is well in the spirit of the game to craft Wonders that are not physical objects. Your examples do all make sense to me, but I can think of other examples that are quite common in the "[mad scientist / mad engineer](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lpgnhdNUiJ1qbh26io1_500.jpg)" genre and are not physical objects: alterations of themselves and/others (through genetic manipulation, injections, nanobots, brainwashing, etc). A Genius (or their pet / sidekick) may have the ability to:

- alter emotions, like the [Mule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_%28Foundation%29) from Asimov or [Prince Xizor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Xizor) from Star Wars.
- activate minions that have been subliminally trained with a word or gesture of command, similar to the way [cylons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylon_%28reimagining%29) are activated / deactivated (this is similar to your third example).
- get mutant / supernatural abilities, like the [Green Goblin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Goblin).

Another possibility for the 21st century is the software genius that has created a software that has virally infected **every** computer in the world, giving her access to every computer if she [presses some sequence of characters](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThePasswordIsAlwaysSwordfish), and/or giving her the access to every fact-checking question she has ("*if only we knew where he is... he could be anywhere in the world*", "*gimme a second... here is a phone box, I will ask my computers*", "*I did not know you had a computer*", "*they are all mine*"), or giving her unlimited funds from any cashpoint (like John Connor in Terminator II), or any other appropriate effect.